# How to clear Select Box old Data & Fill with new Data on Selection Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, select, dropdown

I have 2 drop downs, this thing here is when user select BMW i want to fill data 1,2,3,4,5 & when he selects Volvo i want to display 5,6,7,8,9. Data is getting populated in second drop down but i can see old data as well & as many times i click the list is getting increased. I want to show only specific data on selection & data should also not get repeated. below is my approach.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
            if(x=='BMW'){
                var select = document.getElementById("participant");
                var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
                for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var opt = options[i];
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent = opt;
                    el.value = opt;
                    select.appendChild(el);
                }
            }
            if(x=='Volvo'){
                var select = document.getElementById("participant");
                var options = ["6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
                console.log(options)
                for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var opt = options[i];
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent = opt;
                    el.value = opt;
                    select.appendChild(el);
                }
            }

        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Type</option>
        <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
        <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <select id="participant">
        <option>select</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `innerHTML` of the `<select>` before adding new `<option>`.

```js
function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
            var select = document.getElementById("participant");
            //this line clears the old data.
            select.innerHTML = '<option>Select</option>'    
            if(x=='BMW'){
                
                var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
                for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var opt = options[i];
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent = opt;
                    el.value = opt;
                    select.appendChild(el);
                }
            }
            if(x=='Volvo'){
                var options = ["6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
                console.log(options)
                for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var opt = options[i];
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent = opt;
                    el.value = opt;
                    select.appendChild(el);
                }
            }

        }
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Type</option>
        <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
        <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <select id="participant">
        <option>select</option>
    </select>
```